# System.Windows is not defined in *.fs files, but is defined in *.fsx files

Tags: forms, f#

Why it happens so, that if I write code in `fsx` script, then
`open System.Windows` works fine, but if I do it in `fs` file, then it says **System.Windows is not defined**?

Besides, I've read and heard, that `fsx` and `fs` are pretty much same files, except that `fsx` is interactive, whereas `fs` is something which gets compiled. However, still, many things that work in one, doesn't work in another and vice versa.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that `fs` and `fsx` are *almost* identical, as far as the F# language goes. The difference is in referenced assemblies.

When you run a script in FSI, the FSI references a bunch of assemblies by default, just to make your experience smoother. One of such "default" references is `System.Windows.Forms`, which incidentally contains the `System.Windows` namespace, thus making your `open System.Windows` work.

When you're compiling your code with a compiler, however, you have to specify precisely which assemblies you want referenced. This is intentional. This helps prevent your compiled program from referencing assemblies that you're not actually using, thus preventing unnecessary bloat.

So if you want your compiled file to have access to `System.Windows.Forms`, you need to add that reference to wherever you're specifying your references, which would depend on how you're compiling.

If you're using a project in Visual Studio, you can right-click the project and choose "Add Reference".
If you're using .NET Core `project.json` file, you can add the reference to the `dependencies` section (see [`project.json` reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json) for more; also note that [`project.json` is going away soon](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/)).
If you're compiling with `fsc.exe` from command line, you can use the `-r` option to add the reference (see [`fsc.exe` options reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-options) for more).